# Outlook addin: Get elements from a selected calendar

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin, visual-studio-addins

I'm creating an Outlook add-in and i'd like to know how to get elements from a selected calendar?
For exemple, i need to get all Appointments items from a calendar named "myCalendar". 
Now, i can just get all appointments items from ALL calendars.

thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those extra Calendars are available as subfolders of the main Calendar folder. So here is what you do:

1. Get a reference to the main calendar folder using

   Outlook.MAPIFolder calendar = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
2. Enumerate the `calendar.Folders` collection until you find one with the `MAPIFolder.Name` you are looking for.
3. From that MAPIFolder, enumerate all `Items` as `Outlook.AppointmentItem` like you are already doing.

Comment: I don't mind the unaccept. I _would_ however like to learn what is wrong with the answer.