# Cannot find a specific Outlook Calendar

Tags: c#-3.0, automation, outlook

I'm trying to find a specific Outlook calendar.  I've looked at the instructions from this [Outlook addin: Get elements from a selected calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120681/outlook-addin-get-elements-from-a-selected-calendar).

When I try to implement it with this code:

```
public static MAPIFolder GetTimeTrackingCalendar()
{
MAPIFolder result = null;
MAPIFolder calendars = (MAPIFolder)outlook.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
for (int i = 0; i < calendars.Folders.Count; i++)
{
    if (calendars.Folders[i].Name == "MyTimeTracker")
    {
        result = calendars.Folders[i];
        break;
    }
}
return result;
```

}

I get an error saying Array index out of bounds. Inspecting the calendars object, they're two folders but none support the Name property.  Am I missing a cast?

Thanks, Bill N

Comment: It's been a while (that's why a comment and not an answer), but IIRC that the iteration should be 1-based instead of 0-based. I could be wrong, though. :)

Comment: Thanks Ken.  That was it.  I wonder why when I inspect the calendar object and look at the two Folders, I don't see the Name property.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, Outlook (and the other Office automation objects) use 1-based indexes instead of 0 based. This is what causes the "array index out of bounds" error.

Changing the loop like this fixes it:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= calendars.Folders.Count; i++)
{
    if (calendars.Folders[i].Name == "MyTimeTracker")
    {
        result = calendars.Folders[i];
        break;
    }
}
```