# Excel Cell value from Outlook Calendar

Tags: excel, outlook

Hello This post is the only one I could find on the subject.
[Outlook addin: Get elements from a selected calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120681/outlook-addin-get-elements-from-a-selected-calendar)

I have an excel spreadsheet template that I print before all my meetings.  It contains the meeting Location, which group name and the meeting time.

I have to manually enter the time, and location so that at the end of the week when I write up the meeting minutes. All the critical info is already printed on my notes sheet. I have three weekly meetings that I have to keep my notes organized for.

Q: is there a way to open an excel spreadsheet to pull values from the current day outlook calendar.

I would like to avoid VBA if possible.

Comment: You can't without VBA. At least, you may find on the shelf add-in or software that would do such a thing

Comment: You can find some inspiration in the link you've included in your question. You can have a try and show us the code you've built. We will then be able to help you where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

You need to use VBA, or some programming language that can access the Application automation servers, to automate this. VBA lends itself to the task because it doesn't need a separate compiler but can be written in Excel and run from there.

Take a look at these references to get started:

[Getting Started with VBA in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737.aspx)

[Automating Outlook from VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206737%28v=office.12%29.aspx)